# GLSL. Get a pixel color in a fragment shader

Tags: opengl, glsl

I trying to implement a mouse picker based on color coding and try to build it on fragment shader. My color ID is a color value of vertices in fragment shader, but a true fragment color defines from texture. Is there the way to read color in current mouse coordinate directly in the shader?
My fragment shadder:

```
#version 330 core
out vec4 color;
out vec3 mouseColor;

in VS_OUT {
   vec3 color;
   vec2 texCoords;
} fs_in;

uniform sampler2D texture;
uniform vec2 mousePos;


void main()
{ 
   color = texture2D(texture, fs_in.texCoords);
   mouseColor = ???
}
```

I know how to read a pixel color in current coordinates from texture:

```
 mouseColor= texture2D(texture, mousePos);
```

but how to read pixel from a current screen picture?

Comment: You cannot access the current render target from within the shader. Render the scene and then use the data in a second pass.

Comment: Google glReadPixels.  That's how you'd read it back from the framebuffer.

Comment: Thanks to both of you!

Comment: This is old but depending on the program you could have the cpu set the mouse XY as a uniform vector2, then you could have the mouse xy coords available for use in your first shader pass.